# Create an instance of a Map<string, IDoSomethingWith<Something>

Tags: typescript

How do I create in instance of this generic `Map` using TypeScript?

```
Map<string, IDoSomethingWith<Something>>
```

I tried:

```
const test: ReadonlyArray<string> = ['somekey'];
new Map<string, IDoSomethingWith<Something>>(test)
```

But I don't know how to pass the instance of `IDoSomethingWith<Something>`.

I'm getting this error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReadonlyArray<[string, IDoSomethingWith<Something>]>'.'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
 interface IDoSomethingWith<T> {

}

class DoSomethingWith<T> implements IDoSomethingWith < T > 
{

}

 class Something
{

}

let test2: ReadonlyArray<[string, IDoSomethingWith<Something>]> = 
    [["test2", new DoSomethingWith<Something>()]];
let myMap = new Map<string, IDoSomethingWith<Something>>(test2)
myMap.set("test", new DoSomethingWith<Something>())
let testGet = myMap.get("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
new Map<string, IDoSomethingWith<Something>>([['somekey', new DoSomethingWith<Something>()]])
```